# how to optimize a .kafka producer in java.?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, microservices

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Value("${kafka.boot.server}")
    private String kafkaServer;

   @Bean    
   public KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate(){
       return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerConfig());}

   @Bean
   public ProducerFactory<String,String> producerConfig() {
       Map<String,Object> config= new HashMap<>();
       config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
       config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class );
       config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonSerializer.class);          return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
   }
}
```

What are the prerequisites for kafka? What do you suggest for publishing message? What other ways possible are there?

Comment: Why do you need to optimize?

Comment: What you wish to achieve by improving configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `delivery.timeout.ms`:
   If massive events appear in a short time is your case, this value should be higher because when the network is busy, your client will complain about `NetworkException`, and increasing it you can see less `NetworkException`.

Understanding what is `delivery.timeout.ms`:

[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer?source=post_page-----fa3910d9aa54----------------------#KIP-91ProvideIntuitiveUserTimeoutsinTheProducer-TestPlan](https://KIP-91)

2. `acks`: If you need no data loss. You have to set it to `all`. The default is 1 and
   the leader will write the record to its local log but will respond without awaiting full acknowledgement from all followers. In this case should the leader fail immediately after acknowledging the record but before the followers have replicated it then the record will be lost.
3. `retries`: It depends on your kafka client version. Now the default retries is Integer.Max,
   but for the earlier versions you will like to set `retries` to a higher value so your producer does not stop due to one simple exception that the leader partition is not reachable.
4. Exactly-once: If you app requires exactly-once, You have to refer to `enable.idempotence` and `transactional.id`

Note that the configs mentioned here should be possible to find the corresponding `enums` in your java client

Further reference of producer settings:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html